# Is Ionic PWA Secure?

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

Would like to seek for advise regarding is Ionic PWA safe as server-side coding.

Will user able to hijack Ionic PWA code / function?
Is it save to perform secure transaction like login with different privilege, manipulate data, place order using Ionic PWA.

Really appreciate for open discussion / advise.

Comment: Regarding the security of server side functionality, it is better to integrate your App to secure environment like [Firebase Hosting using Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/serverless-overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Realize that Ionic framework and PWA are only for ***Client* side**.

As any Client side code, an attacker can inspect it however they like and mess with it on their machine, reverse engineer it, etc. But that would mainly give them control on their locally installed app.

You are free to implement any Server technology and configuration as Backend for your Ionic PWA Client app.

That is where (almost) all security features belong.

Once you have proper security in your backend, any Client side code will do, as long as you also implement security features to prevent e.g. XSS, communication interception, etc. In this regard, you can implement them just the same whether Ionic and/or PWA or not.